# Using view_context inside the Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I'm using `ActiveJob` to send mails:

## Using `deliver_now` method:

#### invoices_controller.rb

```
def send_invoice
  #other stuff
  Members::InvoicesMailer.send_invoice(@invoice.id, view_context).deliver_now
end
```

#### invoices_mailer.rb

```
require 'open-uri'
class Members::InvoicesMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def send_invoice(invoice_id, view_context)
    @invoice = Invoice.find(invoice_id)
    attachments["#{@invoice.identifier}.pdf"] = InvoicePdf.new(@invoice, view_context).render

    mail :to => @invoice.client.email, :subject => "Invoice"
  end
end
```

*Notice here that I'm sending the `view_context` from the controller to the mailer, that will again pass it to the `InvoicePdf` class to generate the invoice.*

**Result:** Email sent correctly

## Using `deliver_later` method:

#### invoices_controller.rb

```
def send_invoice
  #other stuff
  Members::InvoicesMailer.send_invoice(@invoice.id, view_context).deliver_later
end
```

**Result:** `ActiveJob::SerializationError in Members::InvoicesController#send_invoice Unsupported argument type:` `view_context`.

How to inject the `view_context` inside the `InvoicePdf`, either loading it from inside `InvoicePdf`, or `InvoiceMailer`?

#### *Edit: This is what the InvoicePdf looks like*

#### invoice_pdf.rb

```
class InvoicePdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize(invoice, view_context)
    @invoice, @view_context = invoice, view_context
    generate_pdf
  end

  def generate_pdf
    # calling some active_support helpers:
      # @view_context.number_to_currency(//)
    # calling some helpers I created
  end
end
```

Comment: Including the full error trace could be useful.

Comment: I've edited the question. I'm not getting a clear stack trace because the call is made with ajax ...

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b66dcc1f869d22040d798719f5390a9fa102d41c/activejob/lib/active_job/arguments.rb#L19-L23 explains what is happening.

Comment: One way to get around this limitation would be to pass just the information needed as strings or integers.

Comment: Why do you need view context? How the `InvoicPdf` class looks? One way is to create PDF before you send email or the second one is to create `view_context` manually in `InvoiceMailer`. You definitely cannot pass it as an argument to `InvoiceMailer` if you want to use `deliver_later` method.

Comment: @edariedl take a look at the edit, I'm using some active support helpers, and some other custom ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with passing an object like the view context and then using `deliver_later` is that the parameters you give it are serialized to some backend (redis, MySQL), and *another* ruby background process picks it up later.

Objects like a view context are not really things you can serialize. It's not really *data*.

You can just use `ActionView::Base.new`, for example from `rails console`:

```
# New ActionView::Base instance
vagrant :002 > view = ActionView::Base.new

# Include some helper classes
vagrant :003 > view.class_eval { include ApplicationHelper }
vagrant :004 > view.class_eval { include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers }

# Now you can run helpers from `ApplicationHelper`
vagrant :005 > view.page_title 'Test' 
"Test"

# And from url_helpers
vagrant :006 > view.link_to 'Title', [:admin, :organisations]
 => "<a href=\"/admin/organisations\">Title</a>"
```

Here's what I do in my `PdfMaker` class, which is probably similar to your `InvoicePdf` class.

```
    def action_view
        @action_view ||= begin
            view = ActionView::Base.new ActionController::Base.view_paths

            view.class_eval do
                include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
                include ApplicationHelper
                include FontAwesome::Rails::IconHelper
                include Pundit

                def self.helper_method *name; end
                def view_context; self; end
                def self.before_action f; end
                def protect_against_forgery?; end
            end

            view
        end
    end
```